# why my array show in integer instead of float

Tags: c

The question look like this

https://i.imgur.com/u0LJO0g.png

where do i get wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i,n;
    int a[] = {3,5,7};
    float x[] = {0,0,0};

    printf("function f(x)=(x^3-2x^2+10x-5)/(x-10)\n");

    for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
        x[i] = (a[i]^3-2*(a[i]^2)+10*a[i]-5)/(a[i]-10);
    }

    for(n = 0;n<3;n++){
        printf("if x is %d,f(x) is %f\n",a[n],x[n]);
    }
}
```

I expect the output will look that this

```
if x is 3,f(x) is -5.14
if x is 5,f(x) is -24.00
if x is 7,f(x) is -103.33
```

but the actual output is

```
if x is 3,f(x) is -3.000000
if x is 5,f(x) is -7.000000
if x is 7,f(x) is -20.000000
```

Comment: You need to review operators in C as well as being aware of the difference between integer division and floating point division. The ^ operator does not raise a number to a power in C. In C ^ is the exclusive OR (XOR) operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `^` is XOR in C, not exponentiation.
2. If you do math on `int`s you're going to get `int` results. You'll need to cast some of those `a[i]` to `float` or `double` to get floating point arithmetic.